# Polars from_pandas() fails with "ComputeError: only string-like values are supported in dictionaries"

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

Converting a Pandas DataFrame to a Polars DataFrame will result in an error if the Pandas DataFrame has any columns with categorical dtypes that are either `int` or `float`.

For example, this...

```py
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "label1": pd.Categorical([1, 1, 1, 2, 2]),
        "label2": pd.Categorical([0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3]),
        "measurement": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
)

pl_df = pl.from_pandas(df)
```

produces this error...

```
ComputeError: only string-like values are supported in dictionaries
```

This example was original shared [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4172), but no
workaround was suggested. How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that changes the `int` and `float` **categorical columns** to ***regular*** `int` and `float` dtypes.

```py
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl


def pd_to_polars(df):
    """
    Convert a Pandas DataFrame to Polars DataFrame and handle columns
    with int and float categorical dtypes.
    """
    df = df.copy()
    for col in df.columns:
        if isinstance(df[col].dtype, pd.CategoricalDtype):
            if pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype(df[col].cat.categories.dtype):
                df[col] = df[col].astype(int)
                print(f"Column [{col}] cast to int")
            elif pd.api.types.is_float_dtype(df[col].cat.categories.dtype):
                df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
                print(f"Column [{col}] cast to float")

    return pl.from_pandas(df)


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "label1": pd.Categorical([1, 1, 1, 2, 2]),
        "label2": pd.Categorical([0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3]),
        "measurement": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
)

pl_df = pd_to_polars(df)
```